# Объясните почему нажатие кнопок все равно работает

Tags: java, android, android-button

```
package com.example.writeandread;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
//import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText edit;
    private TextView txtShow;
//    private Button btn1, btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
//        btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        txtShow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public void read (View view){
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInput = openFileInput("example.txt");
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fileInput);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
            StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String lines;
            while ((lines = buffer.readLine()) != null){
                strBuffer.append(lines + "\n");
            }
            txtShow.setText(strBuffer.toString());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void write (View view){
        String myTxt = edit.getText().toString();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutput = openFileOutput("example.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutput.write(myTxt.getBytes());
            fileOutput.close();
            edit.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Текст сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Смотрю видеоурок на тему считывания и записи введеного текста в файл на устройство 
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3DR9PjyIYw&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFW13-lP3IgK9lZoM1M-oPl4&index=15&t=0s).

Так вот вопрос, почему добавленные мною кнопки в режиме "дизайн" в AndroidStudio РАБОТАЮТ без подключения соответствующей библиотеки - "Button"(я ее закомментировал) и к тому же без подключения функции прослушивания нажатий кнопок setOnClickListener?

[image: Кнопки]

Comment: В этом коде нет кнопок. Что означает "работают"?

Comment: А где тогда они? По факту я запускаю эмулятор и там есть кнопки которые выполняют свои функции

Comment: Какие у них функции?

Comment: При нажатии одна - записывает введенные в текстовое поле строки, а другая считывает записанный текст и выводит его на экран

Comment: Значит это работает еще предыдущий код, где все это было написано.

Comment: Предыдущего кода нет, весь код был написан при создании нового проекта с нуля

Comment: Попробуйте удалить приложение с девайса и потом установить его заново из студии.

Comment: Без изменений((

Comment: Вообще у вас какой-то интересный диалог получился, а точнее безполезный. Смотрите ответ.

Comment: У вас, видимо, слушатели нажатий на кнопки прописаны в xml разметке. Уберите оттуда слушатели или исзмените сигнатуры методов `write/read`, убрав оттуда аргументы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны понимать что ничего не может работать без реализации, если кнопка визуально работает, это не означает что она выполняет ожидаемые функции: написали текст, нажали `записать`, удалили текст, нажали `прочитать`, работает? А так и должно быть, ибо у вас есть реализация кнопок: `public void write (View view){}` и второй метод `public void read (View view){}`, заккоментируйте их или переименуйте и вы получите ошибку компиляции так как у вас в коде вьюшки кнопки указан параметр `android:onClick="read"` (это не правильное именование предпочтительнее писать: onClickRead), который описывает реализацию. В Java как мне помнится нужно было ещё писать @Override, но это не точно. Почему вам не нужно указывать `ИД` кнопки? За вас это делает сама активити которая при прорисовке экрана находит вьюшку с данным атрибутом, сопоставляет его с таким же методом в коде (этот метод обязательно должен принимать `View`) и всё. Это дин из методов обработки нажатий советую к [изучению](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/button.php).

Comment: Спасибо. Я думал всегда если есть кнопка должна быть функция прослушки кнопки OnClickListener, а оказывается методов обработки нажатий больше чем один))